# Tableau combination chart (2 bars and 1 line chart) does not show the line chart

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a combination chart (2 bars and 1 line chart) in Tableau. However the line chart is not shown even though I have included in the Marks section. However if I undo, Analysis -> Aggregate Measure the line appear but the counts are not correct. Could anyone help.

[View when Analysis -> Aggregate Measure is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYwQJ.png)

[View when Analysis -> Aggregate Measure is deselected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asC4L.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to syncronize the axis when creating a dual axis chart else these type of issues will come.

Right click on second chart and then click synchronize the axis and check the chart.

[image]